# Packages installed within a certain time frame

Tags: package-management, time

Could someone please help me with how I can list the packages that were manually installed within a certain time frame. For instance, If I want to see a list of packages that were manually installed in the past 2 months..how may I go about doing it?

Than you

Answer (score 3):

This is a script using `aptitude` (to be installed) and `dpkg` logs,
change the `date` variable, in format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LC_COLLATE=C

date="2011-05-31"

join -22\
  <(aptitude -F%p search '?installed?not(?automatic)' |
    sort) \
  <(less /var/log/dpkg.log* |
    sort |
    awk -v date="$date" '$1 >= date && $3 == "install" { print $1, $4 }' |
    sort -u -k2,2) |
  awk '{ print $2, $1 }' |
  sort
```

Comment: Isn't there a command that I can use to get the same information? I mean, it seems to me that an important piece of software like 'aptitude' or dpkg must have some options or switches that allow me to get that kind of information directly...without having to resort to a shell script.

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

- If installed as a DEB Ubuntu Software Center tracks when something is installed:

[image]

- Installing from a `tar` would be rather impossible. You would have to know what packages where installed to have a look at the date of creation of the executable.

Comment: I do all my installation through aptitude. So is there a way to use aptitude to query the installed packages in a meaningful way? Thanks